# very fast rotation

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, all,

my robot is rotating very fast. it runs on move_base.
although I have capped the rotation as below in the local path planner and rotate recovery

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.05
  max_rotational_vel: 0.2
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.01

  acc_lim_th: 0.2
  acc_lim_x: 0.5
  acc_lim_y: 0

RotateRecovery:
      max_rotational_vel: 0.2
      min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.01
      acc_lim_th: 0.2
```

it still turns very fast.
especially when the robot set off from its original position.
the max rotational vel printed from cmd_vel topic is upto -1.0
the 0.2 cap seems only effective when robot reaches its destine and trying to adjust its final position.

other then the two rotational velocity about, is there any other place I should be concerning?

thanks

Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188532/very-fast-rotation/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-08-02**:
the nomenclature might be different as @ahendrix mentioned. But I have had similar problems from bringing down the velocities too much. I don't know what the problem source is but increasing the overall velocities and accelerations moderated that problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably also be setting the `min_rotational_vel` or `min_vel_theta` parameter to TrajectoryPlannerROS.

The other parameters to TrajectoryPlannerROS are described on the [base_local_planner wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner?distro=indigo#Parameters)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0